# `cloud-init` does not block VM provisioning

Tags: azure, cloud-init

I use Azure and I would like to use `cloud-init` to install some software on VM creation.

Here is the content of `cloud-init.yml`:

```
#cloud-config

package_update: true
package_upgrade: true

runcmd:
  - curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -
  - add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) stable"
  - apt update
  - apt install -y docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io
  - usermod -aG docker azureuser
  - curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.27.4/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
  - chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose

power_state:
  mode: reboot
  condition: True
```

And here is the `az` command I use to create VM:

```
az vm create \
    --resource-group $GR_NAME \
    --name $VM_NAME \
    --image UbuntuLTS \
    --admin-username azureuser \
    --custom-data cloud-init.yml \
    --generate-ssh-keys
```

When the above command returns I am able to `ssh` into machine but my installation process is still running with `cloud-init` and in fact finishes only after ~3 minutes and the machine reboots.

I expect that VM provisioning should be blocked by `cloud-init` but it is not. Is it possible to force "blocking" behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All Cloud-Init is doing is running your commands once the VM is running, it does not block anyone from connecting to the machine while it is running and there isn't really a way to do that.

You could look at scripting something that disables RDP access on the NSG until the VM has completed provisioning.